# Ansible variables with possibilites

Tags: ansible

Is there possible to create in ansible variables which will give me possibility which package I want to install?

For example I have:

```
Package1
Package2
Package3
```

And I want from ansible to ask me which package I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have interactive actions happen within your playbook, you need to use the prompt module

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html